# Barplot legend with entry only for second sub-bar

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, legend

I'm new to *R* and currently experimenting with drawing bar plots for a contingency table. Now I'd like to have a legend in my plot with only one label named "*Extra*", which corresponds to the **second** row in my table. I tried

```
legend.text = c("","Extra")
```

but this draws two labels, while

```
legend.text = c(NULL,"Extra")
```

draws only one label, but with the color of the first sub bar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `identical(NULL, "") #[1] FALSE` They are not the same in r. Or `is.null("") #[1] FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I understand what you are asking.  You can manipulate the legend through `args.legend`

```
barplot(2:1, legend.text=c("", "B"), col=2:3,
    args.legend=list(fill=c(NA,3), border=c(NA,1)))
```

[image: Barplot]

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually dealing with a 2x2 contingency table, so I have two bars each consisting of two stacked bars, and I want to have the label only for the second sub-bar (in each bar). Your suggestion of using `args.legend` was the crucial idea. In the end, I used `barplot(tabelle, legend.text=c("Extra"), col=1:2, args.legend=list(fill=c(2)))`, where `tabelle` is my contingency table.

Answer (score 1):

`""` is a character vector with a `length` of `1`.

You can check it like this:

```
length("")
# [1] 1
```

Also, as I mentioned in my comments (and as it obvious based on above):

```
identical(NULL, "")
# [1] FALSE

is.null("")
# [1] FALSE
```

If you pass a character, any character vector including this *"blank"* one, to your legend it would get printed while passing `NULL` makes it to be omitted form your plot.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not so much about what NULL does, but primarily about how to omit the first row of my contingency table in the legend. I just included these lines to show my effort.